# C# SendMessage not working in windows 10

Tags: c#, sendmessage, buttonclick

I try to simulate button click using sendmessage.

Here is the declaration:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, int msg, int wParam, String lParam);
```

Here is the code:

// get window handle through change password link
IntPtr objHandle = new IntPtr();

```
        objHandle =getWindowObjHandleByText(ChangePasswordLink,(IntPtr)hwnd);

            // click the change password
        SendMessage((int)objHandle,0x00F5, 0, null);
```

The sendmessage works perfect on windows 7 machine but Sendmessae doesnt work on windows10.

Kindly advice.

Comment: I'm immediately suspicious of a P/Invoke signature that contains so many `int`s. May not be your current issue but so far as I'm aware, many of those (except `msg` I think) should be `IntPtr`s.

Comment: [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);