# SendMessage and PostMessage not working on windows 10

Tags: c#, windows-10, sendmessage

I have an application that emulates keystrokes in a window. Everything worked well for Windows 8. But I can't get this to work on Windows 10.
declarations:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, WM wMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);     
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, WM wMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
```

And code:

```
    private void KeyPress(IntPtr handle, IntPtr vk)
    {
        try
        {
            if (handle == IntPtr.Zero)
                return;
            SendMessage(handle, WM.KEYDOWN, vk, IntPtr.Zero);
            SendMessage(handle, WM.KEYUP, vk, IntPtr.Zero);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //TODO Add logs
        }
    }
```

I found same question here with no answers: [C# SendMessage not working in windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38911567/c-sharp-sendmessage-not-working-in-windows-10)
I also tried SetForegroundWindow(handle) and SendKeys.Send.

Any advices?

Comment: We'll need more information to help, are you trying to send a message to another program? Within your own? How are you getting the `HWND` to send to?

Comment: What window are you trying to send the messages to? Does the window belong to an elevated process (UIPI)? Add `SetLastError = true` to your `DllImport` attributes and examine the error codes.

Comment: HWND:           
 var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(Settings.ProcName).ToList();
            var handles = processes.Select(p => p.MainWindowHandle).ToList();
I was trying to send message to notepad. And also I created simple winform app which only has a TextBox.

Comment: So are those processes elevated ones? What is the error code from [Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getlastwin32error?view=net-5.0)?

Comment: Yes, all processes including my app are elevated. I added SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode to DllImport and  Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() returns 0